# How to upload multiple image using wp_insert_post

Tags: php, wordpress

Im using wp_insert_post to add products on the front end of a woocommerces site

My current code will upload all the images but only the last image will be in the product gallery images

heres my code;

functions.php

```
function my_handle_attachment( $file_handler, $post_id, $set_thu=false) {
  // check to make sure its a successful upload

  if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();

  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

  $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );


  if ( is_numeric( $attach_id ) ) {

    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_product_image_gallery', $attach_id );

  }
  return $attach_id;  
}
```

frontend

```
if ( $_FILES ) {
    $files = $_FILES['upload_attachment'];
    foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($files['name'][$key]) {
            $file = array(
                'name'     => $files['name'][$key],
                'type'     => $files['type'][$key],
                'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
                'error'    => $files['error'][$key],
                'size'     => $files['size'][$key]
            );
            $_FILES = array("upload_attachment" => $file);
            foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
                $newupload = my_handle_attachment($file,$post_id);
            }
        }
    }
}


<input type="file" name="upload_attachment[]" multiple="multiple"  />
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: if only the last pic is getting saved, there must be a problem in the for each loops I believe.

Comment: Do you see any issue? all images are being uploaded but only the last one is going into the product gallery.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing this in your code and try once, I remember this while working on my wordpress project so.

```
    $attachment_id = media_handle_upload($file, $post_id);
    update_post_meta($post_id,  array_push($post_id, '_product_image_gallery', 
    $attachment_id));
    return $attachment_id;
```

Comment: No, Just tried this, it doesnt work no images are getting added to the product gallery but they are getting attached to the right product in the media section.

Comment: Well my code does that and adds one image to product gallery. Is there anything else you did to get this working?

Answer (score -1):

please try this

```
function my_handle_attachment($file_handler, $post_id)
{
  if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

 $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );
 if (is_numeric($attach_id )) 
 {
 update_post_meta( $post_id, '_product_image_gallery', $attach_id );
 array_push($post_id, '_product_image_gallery', $attach_id)
 }
 return $attach_id;  
}
```

Comment: This didnt work its doing the same thing as my code only the last image is showing in the product gallery section.